# Write in SQL connection to trigger LOCK IN SHARED MODE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

Assume you have two SQL connections in PHP. MySQLi objects.

```
$sql1
$sql2
```

Both have auto commit disabled.

`$sql1` selects values from rows and locks them with LOCK IN SHARE MODE.

`$sql2` performs inserts and updates based on input read by $sql1.

So the question: Does $sql1 actually lock the row when the transaction for the connection ONLY performs SELECT. I ask because it's not normal to use transactions when only selecting data (as far as I'm informed).

I need the rows touched by $sql1 to not change until all inserts and updates have been committed by $sql2.

I do a commit for $sql1 to release the lock after $sql2 is done (and committed), despite the fact that $sql1 never wrote any data. Is it designed to work this way?

I cannot do it on the same object, as the inserts and selects are performed by prepared statements in a loop, requiring two different objects.

Edit with additional info:

MySQL 5.6.22

Isolation level is default (REPEATABLE READ)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following links relate to the topics you're interested in.  The answer will have to consider that you are using auto commit disabled, REPEATABLE READ isolation level, and LOCK IN SHARED MODE.  Changing any one of these settings can actually end up changing your experience in different ways.

That said, I'm more used to MS SQL Server, and with auto commit type behavior.  And still, I've very familiar with, and would generally expect selects to take out a shared lock.  So, to the "is this common" question, I'd say yes.

> Note
>
> Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when
>   autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START
>   TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled,
>   the rows matching the specification are not locked.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html